# Constructing dict with arbritary number of key/value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to know if the above is possible. I currently have a list of dictionaries (# of dictionaries in the list is arbritary). I will have to 'copy' the dictionaries from the list into another dictionary which will be the payload to my HTTP post request. An example below should make this clearer:

```
myList = [{'updates[123]': '1'}, {'updates[234]': '2'}, {'updates[345]': '3'}]
```

Then I will need to copy it into another dict.

```
payload = {
    'updates[123]': '1',
    'updates[234]': '2',
    'updates[345]': '3'
    }
```

Is it possible to create your 'payload' dictionary not knowing the number of elements in the original list, or is the only way just to have if else cases where it checks for `len(myList)` in order to index the correct number of times?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just loop and combine the dictionaries:

```
payload = {}
for d in myList:
    payload.update(d)
```

or using a single dict comprehension:

```
payload = {k: v for d in myList for k, v in d.items()}
```

or using a generator expression and `dict()`:

```
payload = dict(kv for d in myList for kv in d.items())
```

or using `functools.reduce()`:

```
from functools import reduce

payload = reduce(lambda d1, d2: d1.update(d2) or d1, myList, {})
```

In all cases, if there are  duplicate keys, the key-value from dictionary listed last wins.

Performance comparison:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from random import choice, randint
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> testdata = [
...     {''.join([choice(ascii_letters) for _ in range(randint(10, 25))]): None 
...     for _ in range(randint(1, 5))} for _ in range(100)]
>>> def loop(myList):
...     payload = {}
...     for d in myList:
...         payload.update(d)
...
>>> def dictcomp(myList):
...     {k: v for d in myList for k, v in d.items()}
...
>>> def genexpr(myList):
...     {k: v for d in myList for k, v in d.items()}
...
>>> def with_reduce(myList, _reduce=reduce):
...     _reduce(lambda d1, d2: d1.update(d2) or d1, myList, {})
...
>>> def trial(f, testdata):
...     t = timeit.Timer('f(l)', globals={'f': f, 'l': testdata})
...     loops, time = t.autorange()
...     print(f'{f.__name__:>12}: {(time/loops) * 1000000:0.1f} µs')
...
>>> for f in (loop, dictcomp, genexpr, with_reduce):
...     trial(f, testdata)
...
        loop: 24.6 µs
    dictcomp: 34.7 µs
     genexpr: 35.6 µs
 with_reduce: 35.2 µs
```

So of all the options, the simple `for` loop is the most efficient.